# What are the best practices for PHP syntax when used within HTML?

Tags: php, html

I was wondering what the best practice is when using PHP within HTML? Would you use short tags for echo? Would you use curly brackets on if/else statements etc?

Please no comments on using a templating system or that I should be using MVC. I am working on a project that I have been asked to update and ammend.

Here is a block of code that I have written:

```
<div class="left">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($data['vars']['groupslist'][1] as $key => $group): ?>
        <li><?php echo $group->title; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Notice I have used `:` and `endforeach;`. What would you do?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste ;)

Comment: I won't use short_open_tag for compatibility issues at first and for save my eyes on second (the tend to cross each other when finding for a lot <?=$something in a page )

Comment: Not only it's a matter of taste, this question also already has been answered, like [What's the best way to separate PHP Code and HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-php-code-and-html) or [PHP as a template language, or some other PHP templating script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605/php-as-a-template-language-or-some-other-php-templating-script) and the numerous other ones, please use the search.

Comment: *"Please no comments on using a templating system"* - you ***are*** using the PHP build in templating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP templates, that's exactly the way I do it, too (`foreach`/`endforeach`).

But really, when it comes to syntax, this is simply a matter of preference. Thus, no "best practice". Go with what you like and - more importantly - **stick to it**!

I'm sure there are good reasons for either approach.

Comment: Great addition to this topic. Especially the "stick to it" part.

Answer (score 3):

My code would look like something as this:

```
<div class="left"> 
    <ul> 
        <? foreach ($data['vars']['groupslist'][1] as $group) { ?> 
           <li><?=$group->title?></li> 
        <? } ?> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: I would do the same as this except not use any shorttags. +1 for indentation (4 characters) as it's a good practise to help you see where your loops start and end and also what's being executed inside the loop itself.

I've also just noticed the `<?=`, never actually used this before but I assume it's the equivalent of an `echo`?. The only other difference is I would use echo here but it's all down to personal preference, habits and awareness of techniques because this is one that I don't know of and look forward to seeing what it actually does.

Comment: <?=$x?> is just a short for <?php echo $x; ?> which makes your code a lot more readable. Especially when there are a lot of variables involved.

Comment: thanks @Baszz, I haven't seen this before and I agree it's more readable and quicker to write aswell.

Comment: You would assign the `$key` variable even you don't need it?

Comment: No, I would not...I overlooked that bit. I just copied it from the example. Removed it now.

Answer (score 3):

> Notice I have used : and endforeach; What would you do?

Just that. In PHP mixed with HTML it's harder to figure out which { goes with which }. endif and endforeach are just that much more descriptive.

Comment: IDE support is better for `{}`, they even can jump to the end of the block. That's not possible if you use `:`.

Comment: @hakre Your IDE can't jump to the if( ) related to endif? Mine can (Netbeans). Nevertheless, I generally use indentation to create a visual relationship, that becomes harder when you break out of HTML.

Comment: In my current eclipse 3.6.1 PDT it does not work, as well not with geany. And you're right about the indentation, it often bugs me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Just doing something like

```php
<?php
    foreach( $data['vars']['groupslist'][1] as $key=>$group)
        echo '<li>'.$group->title.'</li>';
?>
```

Shai.

Comment: this one is ugly ans unusable in general and offtopic for this question in particular.

Comment: How exactly is this off topic? He asked how would one do this, i've just shared how i would do it for this specific condition. Unusable? Thats quite an overstatement.

Comment: He is asking how to use PHP within HTML, not HTML within PHP. You have no idea what is the asking and how the good code look

Comment: I wish developers wouldn't have a need to show "Who has the bigger balls". You can check many large OpenSource systems that use this method. It's not the point since it could be a part of larger HTML document while this part just handles the <li>'s . Everyone and his method, i don't think there is any "bad practice" here, and your comments just reek of "wanting to show who's the man", or whatever. Have a great week :)

Comment: every `"just the <li>"` eventually will grow to `<li class="circle"><a href="..">`. If you're going to use a template - use a template. DON'T spoil it "just because you can". Many shitty opensource systems gone bloated this way. It's not about balls, it's about experience.

Answer (score 1):

I would do exactly as you have done. Using short tags may cause you problems if your code is migrated to a server that has short tags disabled. I personally find it hard to read, but that may be because I don't use it.

Using the `foreach` blocks as you have not only makes the source code easier to read, but your HTML will be easier to format too.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer what you've done for this case over alternatives. Though I would use the `<?=` to output `$group->title`

Answer (score 0):

> Would you use short tags for echo?

Definitely yes.
That's exactly what short tags are for.

> Would you use curly brackets on if/else statements etc?

it depends.
Although alternative syntax looks neat, I know no editor which can highlight it, so, I am moving slowly back to curlies for sake of highlighting.

Anyway, you can save yourself typing of `;` at the end of statement with either method.